Arrows from one line to another in align environment
I'm trying to recreate the following equation with arrows on the side using the witharrows package.   
I've got something similar using the following code, but it doesn't look nearly as neat as the original. I want the arrows to have these rounded corners as in the image.
\documentclass[french,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{WithArrows}
        \dfrac{3}{4} x \quad &= \quad \dfrac{2}{7}\\[10pt]
        \dfrac{3x}{4}  \quad &= \quad \dfrac{2}{7} \Arrow[xoffset=-3.5cm,tikz={bend right, '}]{\dots} \Arrow{\dots}\\[10pt]
        3x \quad &= \quad \dots \Arrow[xoffset=-3.5cm,tikz={bend right, '}]{\dots} \Arrow{\dots}\\[10pt]
        x   \quad &= \quad \dots
    \end{WithArrows}
    \]
\end{document}

My guess is that the tikzmark library would be better suited, but I could not work out a solution, since my tikz knowledge is fairly limited.

Here is a possibility using nicematrix and tikz.
The style myarrow replaces the line with the rounded corners path marked with a Triangle arrow. By default the path is to the right, but myarrow=- will draw to the left.
The coordinates in nicematrix use the syntax (1.5-|1) to indicate the middle of row 1 and the left of column 1, so \draw(1.5-|1)--(2.5-|1); will draw a straight line from the middle of row 1 to the middle of row 2, at the left edge of column 1. The myarrow style and anything else (like a node in the middle) can be added.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        decorate, 
        decoration={show path construction, 
            lineto code={\draw[rounded corners, postaction={decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Triangle}}}, decorate}]
                ([xshift=#11mm]\tikzinputsegmentfirst)--++(#1.4,0)|-([xshift=#11mm]\tikzinputsegmentlast);}}
    },
    myarrow/.default={}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 10pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{r@\;c@\;l}
\dfrac{3x}{4} & = & \dfrac{2}{7}\\
2x & = & \cdots\\
x & = & \cdots
\CodeAfter
  \tikz{
    \draw[myarrow=-](1.5-|1)--node[left=5mm]{$\cdots$}(2.5-|1);
    \draw[myarrow=-](2.5-|1)--node[left=5mm]{$\cdots$}(3.5-|1);
    \draw[myarrow](1.5-|last)--node[right=5mm]{$\cdots$}(2.5-|last);
    \draw[myarrow](2.5-|last)--node[right=5mm]{$\cdots$}(3.5-|last);
  }
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}


It would be interesting to explain the tikzinputsegmentfirst and tikzinputsegmentlast macros.
